# SSIS script task pre-compile script into binary code set to false

Tags: ssis

If I set pre-compile script into binary code to true I get error saying "The task is configured to pre-compile the script, but binary code is not found."
If I set this property to False then it works. Will it be a problem after I deploy package on production server?
Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary code would need to be pre-compiled if you are running production in 64-bit, is this the case?  Sounds like there is a syntax error in your script code though, can you post it here so we can see what the problem might be?

Comment: Also, this MS Support article may be of use...

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/932557?p=1

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure about production server I'll check that.
Here is my script
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.IO

Public Class ScriptMain

    Public Sub Main()

        If File.Exists(CStr(Dts.Variables("strFileLocation").Value)) Then
            Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
        Else
            Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure
        End If

    End Sub

End Class

Comment: That script runs fine in my package (on SQL 2005).  I think the support article fix might be your best bet.

Comment: I think so. By the way I don't think so it will happen in near future and I am thinking of alternative. Instead of file check I'll directly try to read the file and if file is not there it will thro w error and on this event I can send an email. But this has limitaion how I can find the error is because of  source file? Is there any way in OnError event handler to identify error code and then send email?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any problem if you don't have to deploy to a 64-bit machine. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137640%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

> If the script is precompiled it will
>   start more quickly and the script can
>   run in a 64-bit environment. However,
>   the package size is larger when it
>   contains precompiled scripts.
>   Moreover, compiled script cannot be
>   debugged

This a problem acknowledged by Microsoft (in Sql Server 2005), and you can find a fix [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932556/%5BEN%5D/)

Answer (score 0):

Just to inform that I tried this update in my SQL Server and it never worked. I had to set precompile in the script task properties to off

Answer (score 0):

In my simple C# script task, I was getting the error -

```
Package Validation Error

Error at Send Mail: The binary code for the script is not found. Please 
open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and 
make sure it builds successfully. Error at Send Mail: There were 
errors during task validation.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
```

In my case I was just using a simple try catch block to catch Exception in simple code. I added a `using System.Exception;` I got the error after that. I just realized that this import is not needed and is the cause of the error. I don't know why it causes an error in SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had forgotten to add the reference to `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll`.

I was able to solve it by reading the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-reference-the-ews-managed-api-assembly), which describes how to reference it.